# flex-flow: row wrap - displaying as column and not a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For some reason flexbox is not dispalying my content in a row. The flex option is wrapping even in full screen mode before the screen becomes smaller. Not sure why it's doing this. I've attached a screenshots with the code so you can see what I mean. I was expecting the image to be on the right of the text.
[image: My text and image isn't being displayed in a row even though the browser is in full screen mode. The wrap seems to be kicking in]

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: 0;
}

li,
a {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303133;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.section2-h1 {
 font-size: 56px;
 font-family: "Roboto";
}

button {
 width: 176px;
 height: 47px;
 background: #6442ff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
 align-items: center;
 border: none;
}

.section2-head {
 margin: 160px;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section2-text {
 max-width: 537px;
 margin-right: 74px;
}

.button {
 margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section2">
        <header class="section2-head">
            <div class="section2-text">
                <h1 class="section2-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. 
                </h1>
                <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
                <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="" class="section2-img">
        </header>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How big is your image? Flex children do not automatically size to fit in a row, you need to specify properties for those elements as well.

Comment: The image was sized specifically for its place using figma and photoshop. Image width is 528px and the height is 396.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is too big for the row, flex is working properly and wrapping your image underneath the text because there is no more space. I know you say the image has been sized specifically for that area but with the margins you have on the parent and the text wrapper its being push underneath.

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add working code to show how to fix it.

Comment: @disinfor I would but the image in the example is still linked locally so if I included a working code example it wouldn't be suitable. Pointing out the problem was the only thing to do.

Comment: You can use a service like https://via.placeholder.com/528x396 - that gives you the image.